# ¿Qué consulta indicada debo usar en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla llamada `tabla`, la cual tiene **3 campos**:
`id`, `fecha`, `inicio`

En ella está la siguiente información:

```
id   |    fecha      |  inicio

 1   |  21/05/2019   |   6  
 2   |  21/05/2019   |   18            
 3   |  23/05/2019   |   6   
 4   |  21/05/2019   |   23  
 5   |  20/05/2019   |   12  
 6   |  21/05/2019   |   17
```

Qué puedo hacer para que me muestre las filas 2 y 4, si necesito consultar la fecha mayor o igual del `21/05/2019` y mayor de `17` del campo inicio?

Está consulta me debería arroja los id número 2 y 4, lo hago así y me imprime solo el id 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE fecha >= '21/05/2019' AND inicio > '17'
```

¿Qué me hace falta?

Comment: Deberias de agregar la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: Hola, esa es la estructura que tengo en este momento, y en la cual estoy realizando el query. Gracias

Comment: Me refiero a que tipo de datos son las columnas.

Comment: Hola, ok, que pena..xD, el id es int(3), fecha varchar(20), inicio int(3).

Comment: Intenta esto `SELECT * FROM \`tabla\` WHERE fecha >= '21/05/2019' AND inicio > 17`

Comment: Hola, gracias, aunque esa consulta ya la realice e inclusive la agregue en la pregunta..xD

Comment: Creo que deberias de guardar la columna `fecha` como tipo `DATE` y no como `VARCHAR`

Comment: La diferencia entre tu consulta y la mia son las comillas en el `17`

Comment: Hola, gracias, también lo intente con la sugerencia que envió y el resultado fue el mismo..xD

Comment: Hola que tal, es raro, la consulta a simple vista estaria bien, el campo de las fechas siempre te conviene guardarlo como DATE para un mejor manejo de los datos.....

Comment: Consejo: No almacenes fechas como cadenas de caracteres. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas la información de los tipos de dato de las columnas. ¿Te has asegurado que los registros no tengan almacenados espacios de más? Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues un par de aclaraciones, dices requerir la data después de las siguientes condiciones:

- La fecha mayor o igual a `2019-05-21`
- El campo inicio mayor a 17

Entonces la consulta debe ser tan simple como

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE fecha >= "2019-05-21" AND inicio > 17;
```

- El campo `fecha` debería ser `DATE` o `DATETIME` para poder operar las fechas con el formato indicado para almacenarse
- La columna inicio guarda solamente números, por lo que si es de tipo `INT` no se tienen que poner entre comillas sus valores; entonces en tu consulta debe ir así `>17`
- Aquí tienes un enlace con un ejemplo [funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=496fef451b13964ad97f80d89d475ccf)

Aclaro que aunque existe una respuesta similar, yo no traté en la consulta al 17 como cadena de texto pues lo puse sin comillas y además lo trate con la condición de mayor que `>, además que anexé un ejemplo donde el OP puede verificar que dicha consulta sirve.

**Dudas expuestas por la OP en la zona de comentarios de mi respuesta**

Hacer esto

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE fecha >= "2019-05-21"
```

Mostrará en el DATASET de resultados, también la fila con fecha del 23 de mayo, pues nuestra consulta dice *muestrame todo donde la fecha sea igual o mayor a 21 de mayo*

Después tenemos

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE fecha >= "2019-05-21" AND inicio > 17
```

Mostrará solamente 2 renglones, pues aunque la fecha del 23 de mayo entra en el rango señalado queda fuera de la selección de datos debido a que su inicio es de 6 y por lo tanto ese valor es menor al solicitado en la condición.

> Recordar que el operador `AND` pide que tanto la condición de la
>   izquierda(fecha `>=`) y la condición de la derecha(inicio `>` 17) se
>   cumplan

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, aclare unas cosas con esta respuesta y otras anteriores sobre la fecha, aunque revise este link y me pude fijar que si tomas dos de los tres registros,deja por fuera el día 23/05/2019, que será?. Gracias

Comment: ¿cuál sería la nueva condición para la búsqueda por fecha, dime como lo intentaste y te lo explico? @CristinaAngel

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder, si trabajamos con esta consulta SELECT * FROM demo WHERE fecha >= "2019-05-21", nos muestra todas las del 21/05/2019 y además la del 23/05/2019, pero al agregarle la condición AND inicio > 17; nos muestra dos del 21 y no muestra la del 23, eso es lo raro.

Comment: No es nada raro @CristinaAngel lo que sucede es que la primer consulta dice **muetrame todo donde la fecha sea mayor o igual a 21 de mayo** y si revisas 23 de mayo es mayor por eso la muestra, segundo la otra consulta dice **muestrame todo donde la fecha sea mayor o igual a 21 de mayo y que el inicio sea mayor a 17** entonces 23 de mayo aunque entra en el rango de fechas, queda descartada por que su inicio es 6 y ese valor es menor a 17 por eso ya no lo muestra

Comment: Hola, ok, es por la segunda condición que se pide mayor a 17, gracias por todo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DAY(fecha) >= '21' AND MONTH(fecha) >= '05' AND YEAR(fecha) >= '2019' AND inicio >= 17
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, aunque la realice y no me arrojo resultado, el campo fecha lo tengo varchar(12), aunque realice lo siguiente y no me arrojo el resultado esperado tampoco:  SELECT * FROM `tabla`  fecha >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y')
AND inicio > 17, gracias.

Comment: Ah ok, entonces debes convertir el campo fecha a Date para poder hacerlo como te dije, intenta hacerlo, usa esta funcion: STR_TO_DATE(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: Esta respuesta creo que es la mas logica, seria super ideal que el campo fecha debe ser tratado como fecha, ya que eso es lo que es..!! [Tutorial de Tiempos y Fechas en PHP y MySQL](https://www.dsi.uclm.es/personal/miguelfgraciani/mikicurri/Docencia/LenguajesInternet0910/web_LI/Teoria/PHP/Material/Tutorial%20de%20PHP%20y%20MySQL%20Tiempo%20y%20Fechas.htm) caso contrario de no querer cambiar el tipo de campo ya que el lenguaje no estará en capacidad de entender que los números guardados en un vachar son realmente una fecha..!

Answer (score 0):

Que tal amig@ espero y te funcione la consulta

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE fecha >= '2019-05-21' AND inicio >= '17'
```

Comment: Hola, no me sirvio, ya esa consulta la había realizado, pero no me arrojo el resultado esperado. Gracias por el aporte